# Prove that $\{n^2f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\}$ is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let , $f$ be entire function such that $|f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)|\le \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$  for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Then prove that $\{n^2f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\}$ is bounded.

From the relation we find that $f(0)=0$. As $f$ is entire so using Taylor's theorem about $z=0$ we get , $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^n.$$

Then from the expression of $n^2f(1/n)$ I could not say that $n^2f(1/n)$ is bounded. How I solve the problem from this or any other way ?

Can anyone give any hints ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: $n^2f(\frac{1}{n}) = \sum_{k>0} a_kn^{2-k}$, where we know the can exclude $a_0$ as you already commented.

Consider this sum term by term: for each $k>1$, it is clear that the term $a_kn^{2-k}$ is bounded in the limit, and for $k>2$, limits to $0$. From this you can show that $|\sum_{k>1}a_kn^{2-k}|$ is bounded.

The only term that is not clearly bounded is $a_1n^{2-1} = a_1n$, which is trivially $O(n)$.

But your condition shows that $n^2f(\frac{1}{n})$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$. Thus, we see that $a_1=0$, so that $n^2f(\frac{1}{n})$ is bounded.

This is the idea, but can be made rigorous with out much change.

Comment: I don't understand that how $n^2f(1/n)$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$ ?

Comment: Since $|f(\frac{1}{n}| \leq \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$, we can get $|n^2f(\frac{1}{n}|\leq \sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

We know $f(0)=0.$ Unless $f\equiv 0,$ there will be a first power series coefficient that is nonzero, say $a_N.$ Then we can write $f(z) = z^Ng(z),$ where $g$ is entire and $g(0) = a_N.$ If $N=1, $ then $|f(1/n)|$ is on the order of $1/n$ as $n\to \infty,$ which contradicts the hypothesis. Thus $N\ge 2,$ giving the conclusion.

Comment: If $N=1$ then $|f(1/n)|=(1/n)g(1/n)$. Where contradiction comes ?

Comment: $|nf(1/n)| =|g(1/n)| \to |g(0)| = |a_N| > 0.$

Comment: Still not clear....

Comment: You need to take more that a few seconds to think about it.